# Use transaction in node-oracledb

Tags: database, oracle, node-oracledb

I need to execute 3 different update statements in a transaction. I am using node-oracle package. Is there an example which shows how transactions are to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Initially You can set `autoCommit` false and once your tasks are completed you can commit it.

by using connection function [connection.commit(function(error))](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-424-connectioncommit)

Example :

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.autoCommit = false;
```

and when connection.execute() is successfully executed you can commit it as below

```
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO test VALUES (:id, :nm)",
    [2, 'Alison'],  // Bind values
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err, conn);
      } else {
        console.log("Rows inserted: " + result.rowsAffected);  // 1
        conn.commit((error)=> { 
           console.log('Error : ', error);
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: But this is for only one case.

Comment: is all update statements need to execute in sequence or parallel ?

Comment: Its required in sequence.

Comment: For that you can create structure like hierarchy, you can execute second update statement in result callback of first execute statement, and third update statement inside the second update statement result call back, Inside the third update statement result you can commit the transaction.

Comment: Your example actually sets autocommit true at the top - which is probably a typo since your description says to set it to false. However since the default is false, you could leave it unset  What you want to do is to set autocommit `true` before the last insert.  This will save a round-trip of an explicit commit().

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones, I have updated the typo, and yes, We can set `autoCommit` true in last insert options, that will save a round-trip of an explicit commit()

Answer (score 1):

There are [examples in the node-oracledb GitHub repo](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).  The examples have been updated to use Node.js 8's async/await style, making it easier to understand and get correct (but don't forget to use `await`).  Also read the [manual](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#transactionmgt).

The example you want is [insert1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/insert1.js) which shows 3 statements forming a transaction.  The first two statements don't commit but the last uses `autoCommit` (which saves the cost of an explicit `commit()`):

```
result = await connection.execute(
  `INSERT INTO test VALUES (:id, :nm)`,
  { id : {val: 1 }, nm : {val: 'Chris'} });

result = await connection.execute(
  `INSERT INTO test VALUES (:id, :nm)`,
  [2, 'Alison']);

result = await connection.execute(
  `UPDATE test SET name = :nm`,
  ['Bambi'],
  { autoCommit: true });  // commit once for all DML in the script
```